# How to use accumulate function to sum a row of values in a variable array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, accumulate

I've been working on a program where I need to be able to sum rows in a two-dimensional array whose number of columns are variables. I should also add that the rows are *"split"* into two parts (part **A**, and part **B**) whose sizes depend on user input.

I can obviously sum a row just using a **for** loop, but I wanted a more elegant solution that would also be easier to set up across the whole program.  I stumbled across the `accumulate` function out of the numeric library, but all examples that I was able to find were exclusively for one-dimensional arrays.

Here's a sample of my problem code:

```
total = partNum[PART_A] + partNum[PART_B];

partStart[PART_A] = 0;
partEnd[FUNC_A] = partNum[PART_A];
partStart[PART_B] = partNum[PART_A];
partEnd[FUNC_B] = total;

double stat[5][total];
double mass_sum = 0.0

func = PART_A;

accumulate(stat[MASS][partStart[func]], stat[MASS][partStart[func]], mass_sum);
```

However, I get a buildtime error which states that:

> Indirection requires pointer operand ('double' invalid')

I assume this is a syntax error, but changing how I defined the array's start and end did nothing to fix the error.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to happen. Could you please add an example of an input and desired output?

Comment: The first two arguments of `std::accumulate()` are iterators that refer to beginning and (one past the) end of a range.  You are passing `stat[MASS][partStart[func]]` (for both arguments) which is an element of an array, not an iterator.

Comment: On a side note, `double stat[5][total]` is only valid C++ if `total` is `const`, if not, you cannot use `total` here (it's a GCC extension if it works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two first argument of `accumulate` are iterators that the function will use to iterate over the range, but you are passing actual element of the array

[Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator) in C++ is a concept that requires certain operations to be valid on your object, as defined per the standard. For instance, pointer types usually match the [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), meaning that you can basically use them to as array-like object (you can increment them with `++`, you can indirect them with `*`, you can access an element at position `i` with `[]`, etc.). I won't go into full details about what are iterators in C++ because it's a whole topic and you can find plenty of references, in particular on the two links I provided.

Back to your problem, what you want is to give `accumulate` iterator to the beginning and the end of your row, or the beginning and the end of your subranges. There are two ways to do this:

- Take the address of the element `stat[MASS][partStart[func]]`, i.e., `&stat[MASS][partStart[func]]`, which will give you the beginning of the range, and then `&stat[MASS][partEnd[func]]` will give you the end of the range. This works because `stat` is as `double stat[5][total]` and the access operator (`[]`) gives you a reference (a `double&`), that you can take the address of, and the element on the row are contiguous in memory (that would not work for a column).
- Use `stat[MASS] + partStart[func]` and `stat[MASS] + partEnd[func]`. In this case, you take the beginning of the row (`stat[MASS]`), which is (or is implicitly convertible to) a pointer to double (`double*`) and you increment that pointer by `partStart[func]` or `partEnd[func]`, giving you the addresses of the elements you want in the row.

So basically:

```
std::accumulate(&stat[MASS][partStart[func]], &stat[MASS][partEndfunc]], mass_sum);
// or
std::accumulate(stat[MASS] + partStart[func], stat[MASS] + partEnd[func], mass_sum);
```